# What type of timestamp is this and how do I convert it to human-readable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv, timestamp

I've been given hundreds of CSV files, all with timestamps I don't recognise. I've been trying my best to find what it is and try to convert them using JavaScript but so far I've had no luck. 
All the instructions I've been given are this: "The Timestamp 39845.03 is a representation of the date 01/02/2009 and the time 00:45." and I was told it's a Microsoft timestamp.

Comment: What is the maximum number of decimal places in these timestamps?

Comment: Do you need to use the timestamp data? Timestamp fields are often used to manage concurrency.

Comment: @digitalbath From a quick look in a few of the files it seems like it's 2, like in the example above.

Comment: @BonyT yes, I need the date and time in a human readable format. I'm putting them into an indexeddb and then displaying them in a table on a webpage via javascript

Comment: Are you sure these aren't star dates?

Answer (score 2):

This is the timestamp format of `Microsoft Excel`. It is some kind of special.
The 1.1.1900 0:0 is 1.0.
The 2.1.1900 0:0 is 2.0.

The part behind the comma expresses the time.

On [ExcelTips: Unix timestamps to Excel](http://excel.tips.net/T002051_Converting_UNIX_Date_Time_Stamps.html) they give a formular that just needs to be inverted to accomblish the conversion.

```
function convertExcelTimeToUnix(excelTime) {
    return (excelTime - 25569) * 86400;
}
```

The result is an UNIX timestamp and can for example be passed to the constzructor of `Date`.

```
var realDate = new Date(convertExcelTimeToUnix(excelTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's the number of days elapsed since 01/01/1900.

```
 var date = new Date('01 jan 1900');
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + 39845.03 * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000);
```

will do it in javascript.

The extra multipliers are fairly obviously to convert it into the milliseconds.

Comment: Looks like the internal format Excel uses, careful for the leap year they intentionally get wrong: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelDateandTimes.htm

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Except it's from the 31st of December 1899 according to the calculator on dateandtime.com.
Now my next problem is writing some JS to convert it, the tricky part being the part after the decimal places...